# Creating a record for a specific user with another HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship

I'm having a problem with creating a record in Rails 4. A user should have the ability to add a url and select specific categories for this url in the same form. The problem is when I attempt to add url and its categories, it only saves the url and not the categories chosen.

Each user can have many urls and each url can have many categories.

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :url
belongs_to :user
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :urls
```

Here is my form for adding a new url

```
<%= form_for(@url) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :url %>
        <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Copy and Paste the url here" %>
    </div>
    <div>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
        <div>
            <%= check_box_tag "url[category_ids][]", category.id %>
            <%= category.name %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the create method in the url controller

```
def create
    @url = current_user.urls.build(params[:url])
    if @url.save
        flash[:success] = "Url added!"
        render :template => "dashboard/index"
    else
        render :template => "dashboard/index"
    end
end
```

The url is being saved but none of the categories you choose from the checkboxes are saved with the url. Is there something more I need to put in the create method for Rails to realize that I want to save the url's categories as well?

Comment: I just wanted to make a comment that more and more people are moving away from HABTM relationships because they're kind of klunky and difficult. More people instead are using the more explicit has_many :through relationship.

Comment: Check the params in the logs to see if they post looks right to you.